# Alterar apenas valores NaN de uma coluna com base em valores de outra coluna

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

Achei que o problema fosse simples, porém  não me parece tão óbvio. Tenho duas colunas de um dataframe: df['Country'] e df['City']. Algumas células da coluna "City" possuem valores NaN e gostaria de substituir esses NaN por outros valores de acordo com o país. Por isso não quero usar o `fillna()` na coluna "City".

Como exemplo, para Singapura, tenho o seguinte comando e respectiva saída:

```
df[df['Country'] == 'Singapore']['City']
    
192    NaN
399    NaN
572    NaN
872    NaN
897    NaN
Name: City, dtype: object
```

Como todas as cidades estão preenchidas com NaN, foi fácil realizar a alteração para *"Sing-other"*. Para isso usei a linha de comando:

`df.loc[df['Country'] == 'Singapore', 'City'] = 'Sing-other'`

No entanto, para cidades cujo país é Hong Kong, gostaria de substituir apenas os valores NaN por *"HK-other"*, preservando os nomes das cidades existentes. Nesse caso, para Hong Kong, tem-se:

```
df[df['Country'] == 'Hong Kong']['City']

11                NaN
35     Cheung Sha Wan
349           Kowloon
559           Central
677               NaN
735               NaN
885               NaN
Name: City, dtype: object
```

Supondo que ainda tenha outros conjuntos de países/cidades a serem substituídos, não posso aplicar tão somente a substituição de NaN na coluna "City" inteira.

Assim, há alguma sugestão para alterar NaN para *HK-other* na coluna 'City', somente se o país for Hong Kong? Grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu pode criar um dicionário com o valor que tu quer preencher os valores nulos para cada país e preencher apenas os valores nulos com os comandos `fillna` e `map`, desta forma:

```
d = {'Singapore': 'Sing-other',
     'Hong Kong': 'HK-other'}

df['City'] = df['City'].fillna(df['Country'].map(d))
```

Dessa forma fica mais facil extender a lista de países que tenham ocorrências nulas nas cidades do que uma estrutura de repetição. 
Inclusive estruturas de repetiçao como **for in** devem ser evitadas sempre que possível por serem lentas e poderem causar gargalos na execução até com DataFrames pequenos

Comment: Testarei aqui. E, de fato, o que notei antes foi haver um problema, ou na leitura do df ou na fonte csv, pois o Pandas parecia reconhecer os valores ausentes, mas não ler.  Gostei da sugestão de usar  o map()!

Comment: @DaniloFranco Testa lá, se der tudo certo tu pode aceitar minha resposta :)

Comment: Resposta aceitadíssima! Rapaz, estou até agora vislumbrando essa linha de código. Vi algumas dicas parecidas nas minhas buscas, mas usavam sempre a mesma coluna. Nunca pensaria em utilizar como vc me mostrou, pois parece que irá alterar os valores da coluna 'Country'.  Tentando entender , mas já felicíssimo pelo resultado. Gratíssimo!

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in df.index:
    if df['Country'].iloc[i] == 'Hong Kong' and df['city'].iloc[I] == 'NaN':
        df['city'].iloc[i] = 'HK-other'
    else:
        pass
```

Experimenta essa condição simples. Talvez se você estiver pelo Jupyter pode ser capaz de dar um warning de slicing, mas vc pode se guiar por essa lógica pra adequar o código da melhor forma.

Comment: Então, revisando aqui, o código substitui todas as cidades por 'HK-other', inclusive as que não estavam como NaN. Estou tentando uma condição do tipo `se país == 'Honk Kong' E cidade == 'NaN'`, ai sim ele altera a célula para 'HK-other'.

Comment: Experimente colocar então a segunda condição ( City == "NaN") como um and após a primeira

Comment: Não use & como condição de and nesse caso, use and mesmo, e não são necessários esses () separando as condições

Comment: Não deu. Vou gerar um dataframe mais enxuto e, sendo o caso, posto-o aqui editando a pergunta. Acho que tem algo a ver com as saídas em boolean quando aplico as condições. Se eu tiver um entendimento e controle sobre elas, acho que conseguirei resolver. Mas posso estar errado também rs.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Problema solucionado. Agradeço ao Gus, pois através de sua resposta, fiz as alterações necessárias para chegar à solução do problema. Transcreverei aqui os detalhes.

Gerei um outro dataframe de teste(é muito útil tentar reduzir o problema ao modelo mais simples possível).

```
data = np.array([['Hong Kong', np.nan],
                ['Hong Kong', 'Central'],
                ['Hong Kong', np.nan],
                ['Hong Kong', np.nan],
                ['Hong Kong', 'Kowloon'],
                ['Singapore', np.nan]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Country', 'City'])
```

O problema consistia em:

- Alterar os valores nulos de 'Hong Kong' para 'HK-other' sem afetar os nomes de cidades e o valor nulo de 'Singapore'

Solução (depois de quebrar a cabeça com vários outros arranjos complicados):

```
for i in df.index:
    if (df.iloc[i][0] == 'Hong Kong') and (df.iloc[i][1] == 'nan'):
        df['City'][i] = 'HK-other'
```

Obviamente que, no dataframe original com o qual estou trabalhando, bastará trocar os índices acima, de acordo com a indexação das colunas.

Porém, um detalhe a ser relatado. O código acima funcionou para esse dataframe de teste, mas não no original. Assim, a dúvida está respondida, o problema que surge agora é que ele não está lendo os valores NaN da coluna original. Eu consigo alterar o valor digitando um a um: `df.['City'][i] = 'HK-other'`, onde i é o índice da linha, mas o mesmo comando não funciona dentro do laço for. Isso, justamente, porque o trecho `df.iloc[i][1] == 'nan'`não encontra o valor nulo, embora o comando `df.isnull().sum()`apontasse o valor nulo na respectiva coluna.

Novamente, a gambiarra para resolver isso foi utilizar o `df['City'].fillna(555, inplace=True)` para substituir os supostos valores ausentes por 555 e então rodar novamente  o laço for com a troca de 'nan' por 555 no código.

Enfim, problema solucionado de todo.